# Why do I get an exception when passing "null" constant but not when passing a "null" string reference?

Tags: c#, .net, reference, argumentnullexception

If I run this code:

```
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "{0}", null ) );
```

I get a `ArgumentNullException` but if I run this code:

```
String str = null;
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "{0}", str ) );
```

it runs just fine and the output is an empty string.

Now the two piece look equivalent to me - they both pass a null reference into `String.Format()` yet the behavior is different.

How id different behavior possible here?

Comment: Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "{0}", (object)null )); This is fine too. Weird.

Comment: String.Format must be doing some work on the 2nd example, perhaps turning it into the null char? `\0` </guesswork>

Comment: @DaveBish Hopefully Jon Skeet can answer why your example doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: The first case is passing in a null reference. The second case is passing in a (non-null) reference to a null string. Fine but significant distinction. Edit: I am not that familiar with C#, but I am assuming "String str = null;" is assigning a value to a declared object. If that's not the case, then I'm probably in error.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just decompile the code to work out what's going on.

```
string.Format("{0}", null)
```

calls the most *specific* applicable overload, which is [`string.Format(string, object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx).

The overloads of `string.Format` are:

```
Format(String, Object)
Format(String, Object[])
Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])
Format(String, Object, Object)
Format(String, Object, Object, Object)
```

Hopefully it's obvious why the last three options are invalid.

To work out which of the first two to use, the compiler compares the conversion from `null` to `Object` to the conversion from `null` to `Object[]`. The conversion to `Object[]` is deemed "better" because there's a conversion from `Object[]` to `Object`, but not vice versa. This is the same logic by which if we had:

```
Foo(String)
Foo(Object)
```

and called `Foo(null)`, it would pick `Foo(String)`.

So your original code is equivalent to:

```
object[] values = null;
string.Format("{0}", values);
```

At this point, hopefully you'd *expect* an `ArgumentNullException` - as per the documentation.

Comment: I bet you meant `string.Format("{0}", values);` on your last line of code. Anyway, there goes a +1 for typing what I was typing, just faster and more accurately ^^'

Comment: Where is the `take my money` button?

Comment: Also, maybe the answer should highlight *why* the compiler picks the most specific version of the function (it's easy to figure out for me, and I know it's even easier for you, but many readers may miss the detail that a `null` literal carries as little type information as a blank piece of paper).

Comment: Why doesn't `string.Format("{0}", (object)null)` throw an exception?  And the docs only mention an exception if the format is null, not the args.

Comment: Try using F12 (go to definition) @juharr, and you will see the difference. It is, in general, very bad practice to supply null for a params argument which is what null without a typecast to object results in.

Comment: @juharr: The docs I linked to state that `ArgumentNullException` is thrown if "format or args is Nothing." - were you looking at the docs for `string.Format(string, object)` perhaps?

Comment: @juharr having one (or more, or all) member of the object array to be null is fine. Having the array itself being null ain't. It'd be nice for the `string.Format(string, object[])` version to default null arrays into empty ones, but it just doesn't do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, I see now. The `null` is passed as a object array if you don't cast it to object.  Casting to object results in the overload that just takes one object parameter.